# Google analytics v3 bypassing authentication

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have super admin who manages the analytics accounts. Clients give thier analytics account(username and password) to the admin.

[This](https://github.com/ronan-gloo/codeigniter-highcharts-library) is v2 library I was using for codeigniter. In this library when username and password is provide (no need for developer keys) the data is pulled from

```
 https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?
```

Auth code is being generated from response from

```
 https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin
```

So here once I have username and password no need to login , no need to authenticate. But queries here runs slow ( too slow). I have to run many queries as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331503/google-analytics-codeigniter-fetching-data-distributed-monthly-over-year). It seems using [REST](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) queries runs way faster.

So my question is:

> Is there any way that I can bypass user login and authentication if I have username and password. And get the access_token?

Comment: I search about the same answer in .net

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is what google calls the [ClientLogin](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps) authentication method. You still can use that with the version 2.4 of the API.

Google Analytics has 2 versions of the API.

**v2.4**

- Recommended Authentication is oAuth2
- Also supports oAuth, ClientLogin and AuthSub, but it's discouraged.
- Responses are always XML

**v3**

- Latest recommended version
- Recommended Authentication method is oAuth2
- Doesn't support AuthSub or ClientLogin
- Responses are in JSON format
- Some features are only available on v3, and future features will only be added to v3.

The version v3 is notably faster than the v2.4. It's better supported and easier to use.

I believe this library you're using was built for v2.3 so maybe you need some tweaks to make it work with v2.4. See [Migrating from 2.3 to 2.4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/#migration). This will require small effort and you could keep using user+password for authentication.

The other option you have is to rewrite the library for v3, start using oAuth2 and enjoy the extra speed and better support.

Comment: @KamranShahid I don't know from where I got the info that 2.4 would be deprecated in April 2015. I can't find that info anymore, so I updated my answer to remove that. v2.3 was deprecated on July 2012. I don't know how long 2.4 will be supported. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-analytics-data-export-api/jSjHGeU51go/discussion